# Installing Purchased App On New Device? [PlayStore ISSUE]

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I have purchased the app ACR (Another Call Recorder) 1 year ago. Now trying to install it again on my 'new device' (formatted phone). However when I press the view button from the 'Order history' page or search it in the Play Store it displays a dollar value and wants me to repurchase the application.

How am I able to install it without repurchasing, from what I have read up I should be able to just install the app, as it was previously purchased.

As a side note some other apps which have purchased just display the **Install** button and do not require me to repurchase.

[image: app purchase]
[image: app link]

Comment: Are you using the same Google account you used with your original purchase?

Comment: @Izzy yes otherwise you wouldn't see it in the purchase history.

Comment: Good point, just wanted to make sure. Sorry, out of ideas then; it should be available for free, and the button labeled "install". If you hit it, does it ask for the purchase confirmation, or head straight for installation?

Comment: @Izzy just prompts to Accept (permissions/installation) and installs normally

Comment: A possibilty that the developer has changed the name of product in some way and thus registered it. Write to the developer quoting the earlier purchase details (would be mailed to registered email) and ask him to enable

Comment: @beeshyams I've contacted the developer few days ago regarding another question I had. I was told that I could only get the licence under the same account, as in it is not transferrable. Or I could just repurchase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by doing the following.

- Install the ACR Licence apk (which I got from my backup, or you could find the file online)
- Open the Play Store page for the app (the button should be showing **Uninstall**)
- Uninstall the application (from within Play Store)
- Done

Now you should be presented with the **Install** button. Installation should work as normal (no re-purchase required).